Translate Correlated Subquery to Power BI
In a TPC example query we have the following:
select
    s_acctbal,
    s_name,
    n_name,
    p_partkey,
    p_mfgr,
    s_address,
    s_phone,
    s_comment
from
    part,
    supplier,
    partsupp,
    nation,
    region
where
    p_partkey = ps_partkey
    and s_suppkey = ps_suppkey
    and p_size = :1
    and p_type like '%:2'
    and s_nationkey = n_nationkey
    and n_regionkey = r_regionkey
    and r_name = ':3'
    and ps_supplycost = (
        select
            min(ps_supplycost)
        from
            partsupp,
            supplier,
            nation,
            region
        where
            p_partkey = ps_partkey
            and s_suppkey = ps_suppkey
            and s_nationkey = n_nationkey
            and n_regionkey = r_regionkey
            and r_name = ':3'
    )
order by
    s_acctbal desc,
    n_name,
    s_name,
    p_partkey;

The outer query can be translated without any issues and very easily but I have issues translating the whole query, especially the part with the WHERE condition that results in a correlated subquery.
How can I make Power BI use the field ps_supplycost as a value to filter on the query subquery such that it returns the min(ps_supplycost) for the columns I am selecting. I have the feeling that Power BI gives me a hard time on that and hopefully, I am just overlooking something fairly simple.
Thanks!
I have tried the filter options, advanced filter options, tried to apply another table, had a look at the CALCULATETABLE and other functions. Everything appears to be very complicated... I think DAX is the way to go but in DAX I have a hard time issuing a subquery that really works like in SQL

Can you provide your model ? Some data ?

My PowerBI model follows exactly what the TPC-DH model here is showing in section 1.2 Database Entities, Relationships, and Characteristics:
https://www.tpc.org/tpc_documents_current_versions/pdf/tpc-h_v3.0.1.pdf

Describe your data and the desired outcome, and then build a solution with DAX. Translating code from another language is just an unnecessary complication.

That is what we are trying to do already. I thought some helpful answer might await here. Awesome advise @RADO, I hoped your answer might provide more specifics

@Eto - I don't think you understand the advice I gave you. To repeat: stop trying to translate SQL to DAX. This is a really bad idea. Instead, provide a data sample, provide expected output, and then ask for help with DAX.

@RADO, I want it to be translated. I am aware that there are several ways but I have to have the subquery ideally "translated as is" instead of getting the results. The reason is that we'd require to execute the same query once in Power BI and once from another SQL client. That's why I am insisting on a "translation". I guess we'll end up applying a different logic. We have to see then how this can be compared to the other query

First, I share the same advice as @RADO (in the comment): it is not recommended at all to translate from SQL to DAX.
Second, here is an improved version of your SQL query :
SELECT
    s.s_acctbal,
    s.s_name,
    n.n_name,
    p.p_partkey,
    p.p_mfgr,
    s.s_address,
    s.s_phone,
    s.s_comment
FROM
    part p
INNER JOIN partsupp ps ON p.p_partkey = ps.ps_partkey
INNER JOIN supplier s ON s.s_suppkey = ps.ps_suppkey
INNER JOIN nation n ON s.s_nationkey = n.n_nationkey
INNER JOIN region r ON n.n_regionkey = r.r_regionkey
WHERE
    p.p_size = :1
    AND p.p_type LIKE '%:2'
    AND r.r_name = ':3'
    AND ps.ps_supplycost = (
        SELECT MIN(ps_inner.ps_supplycost)
        FROM partsupp ps_inner
        INNER JOIN supplier s_inner ON s_inner.s_suppkey = ps_inner.ps_suppkey
        INNER JOIN nation n_inner ON s_inner.s_nationkey = n_inner.n_nationkey
        INNER JOIN region r_inner ON n_inner.n_regionkey = r_inner.r_regionkey
        WHERE
            ps_inner.p_partkey = p.p_partkey
            AND r_inner.r_name = ':3'
    )
ORDER BY
    s.s_acctbal DESC,
    n.n_name,
    s.s_name,
    p.p_partkey

and this is your PBI model based on the documentation you provided :

So your calculation should be something like :
EVALUATE
VAR MinSupplyCost = 
    CALCULATE(
        MIN('partsupp'[ps_supplycost]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('partsupp'), -- I assume the same for 'supplier', 'nation', 'region'),
            'partsupp'[p_partkey] = EARLIER('partsupp'[p_partkey]) &&
            'region'[r_name] = ":3"
        )
    )
RETURN
FILTER(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            'part',
            'supplier'[s_acctbal],
            'supplier'[s_name],
            'nation'[n_name],
            'part'[p_partkey],
            'part'[p_mfgr],
            'supplier'[s_address],
            'supplier'[s_phone],
            'supplier'[s_comment],
            "MinSupplyCost", MinSupplyCost
        ),
        'part'[p_size] = ":1" &&
        CONTAINSSTRING('part'[p_type], ":2") &&
        'region'[r_name] = "The value of :3" &&
        'partsupp'[ps_supplycost] = MinSupplyCost
    ),
    ORDER BY
    'supplier'[s_acctbal] DESC,
    'nation'[n_name],
    'supplier'[s_name],
    'part'[p_partkey]
)


Hi Amira!
Thank you very much, I will have a look. However, if you read my comment above you should have noticed what I am looking for. Thanks in any case, I will test what you shared for sure

Hi Amira! I have one question. You are using ALL with four different table names. Based on this guide here: https://dax.guide/all/ that's not supported as only ColumnName is repeatable. Would you be so kind and let me know how you made the FILTER part work? I just get an error when using the query above.. Thanks!

Can you provide some data for the tables ?

@Eto you are correct it was a typo, I just needed to mention one table and say that you may need to apply the same logic for the other

Of course, I can. How can I share this with you here on stackoverflow? Thanks

You can send me the data on Linkedin

I don't use LinkedIn. I can share a GDrive link with you. That should be fine, right?
